# OpenCv2.2 C++ filter2D

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm transfering matlab code to c++ using OpenCv2.2, In a function (conv2) that is made to be similar to the matlab one, I use filter2D that comes from

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

the problem is the error message that I get :

> OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unsupported combination of source format (=4), and destination format (=4)) 
>   in getLinearFilter, file C:\opencv\sources\modules\imgproc\src\filter.cpp, line 3234
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>
> what():  C:\opencv\sources\modules\imgproc\src\filter.cpp:3234: error: (-213) Unsupported combination of source format (=4), and destination format (=4) 
>   in function getLinearFilter

It's the first time that i see an error like this one. So, i don't realy know if this comes from my instal or from the code.

============================================================================================
Annexe :

Code :

```
void conv2(const Mat &img, const Mat& kernel, ConvolutionType type, Mat& dest)
{
    // fonction trouvée sur le site :
    // http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/07/opencv-equivalent-to-matlabs-conv2-function/
    // par  Timm Linder le 05/07/2011
  Mat source = img;
  if(CONVOLUTION_FULL == type) {
    source = Mat();
    const int additionalRows = kernel.rows-1, additionalCols = kernel.cols-1;
    copyMakeBorder(img, source, (additionalRows+1)/2, additionalRows/2, (additionalCols+1)/2, additionalCols/2, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
  }

  Point anchor(kernel.cols - kernel.cols/2 - 1, kernel.rows - kernel.rows/2 - 1);
  int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;

  filter2D(source, dest, img.depth(), flip(kernel), anchor, 0, borderMode);

  //cvFilter2D(source, dest, img.depth(), flip(kernel), anchor, 0, borderMode);

  if(CONVOLUTION_VALID == type) {
    dest = dest.colRange((kernel.cols-1)/2, dest.cols - kernel.cols/2)
               .rowRange((kernel.rows-1)/2, dest.rows - kernel.rows/2);
  }
}
```

found on this blog :
http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/07/opencv-equivalent-to-matlabs-conv2-function/
(If some one have bether idear to reproduce the conv2 that could be intresting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looking at the [filter2d docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) , - 
it's obvious that you can't work with int32 Mats (type()==4).

you'll have to convert to one of CV_8U,CV_16U,CV_32F,CV_64F

(also consider updating your opencv. 2.2 is quite old)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, 

I changed the format of my Mat from CV_32S to CV_32F and the error vanished.

(As I’m quiet far from my field, comments that I found under blogs articles are welcome)

But still thanks for the answer.